# I cant get this form to send email or redirect to the correct view

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

So I was able to get this code to work when I had Email setup as its own view. But when I changed it to a form in the footer it wont work. whenever I click submit it just reloads the main index page. I have the form written out in its own view and then a renderpage in the footer section of the _layout.cshtml page. Any help in figuring this out would be wonderful as I have been trying to figure it out for a couple days now.

HomeController:

> using System; using System.Collections.Generic; using System.Linq;
>   using System.Web; using System.Web.Mvc; // to give this controller
>   access to the folders models using ToDoListMaster.Models; using
>   System.Net; using System.Net.Mail; using System.Threading.Tasks;
>
> namespace ToDoListMaster.Controllers {
>       public class HomeController : Controller
>       {
>           public ActionResult Index()
>           {
>               return View();
>           }
>
> ```
>     public ActionResult About()
>     {
>         ViewBag.Message = "Your application description page.";
>
>         return View();
>     }
>
>     public ActionResult Purpose()
>     {
>         ViewBag.Message = "Your purpose page.";
>
>         return View();
>     }
>
>
>     public ActionResult Email()
>     {
>         return View();
>     }
>
>
>     [HttpPost]
>     [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
>     public async Task<ActionResult> _footer(user newUser)
>     {
>         if(ModelState.IsValid)
>         {
>             var body = "<p>Email From: {0} {1}</p><p>Message:</p><p>{2}</p>";
>             var Message = new MailMessage();
>             Message.To.Add(new MailAddress("todolistapptest@gmail.com"));
>             Message.From = new MailAddress(newUser.email);
>             Message.Subject = newUser.subject;
>             Message.Body = string.Format(body, newUser.firstName, newUser.lastName, newUser.message);
>             Message.IsBodyHtml = true;
>
>             using (SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient())
>             {
>                 var credential = new NetworkCredential
>                 {
>                     UserName = "*****",  
>                     Password = "*****"  
>                 };
>                 smtp.Credentials = credential;       
>                 smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
>                 smtp.Port = 587;
>                 smtp.EnableSsl = true;
>                 await smtp.SendMailAsync(Message); 
>                 return RedirectToAction("Sent");
>             }
>         }
>         return View("_footer", newUser);
>     }
> ```
>
> public ActionResult Sent() {
>       return View(); }
>       } }

_footer:

> @model ToDoListMaster.Models.user
>
> @{
>       ViewBag.Title = "_footer"; }
>
> #### Got something to say? Say it!
>
> @using (Html.BeginForm(new { @class = "emailForm" }))
>               {
>                   @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
>                   
>                       @Html.LabelFor(m => m.firstName, new { @class = "control-Label" })
>                       
>                           @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.firstName, new { @class = "form-control" })
>                           @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.firstName)
>                       
>                   
>                   
>                       @Html.LabelFor(m => m.lastName, new { @class = "control-label" })
>                       
>                           @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.lastName, new { @class = "form-control" })
>                           @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.lastName)
>                       
>                   
>                   
>                       @Html.LabelFor(m => m.phone, new { @class = "control-label" })
>                       
>                           @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.phone, new { @class = "form-control" })
>                           @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.phone)
>                       
>                   
>                   
>                       @Html.LabelFor(m => m.email, new { @class = "control-label" })
>                       
>                           @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.email, new { @class = "form-control" })
>                           @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.email)
>                       
>                   
>                   
>                       @Html.LabelFor(m => m.subject, new { @class = "control-label" })
>                       
>                           @Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.subject, new { @class = "form-control" })
>                           @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.subject)
>                       
>                   
>                   
>                       @Html.LabelFor(m => m.message, new { @class = "control-label" })
>                       
>                           @Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.message, new { @class = "form-control", @cols = 40, @rows = 10 })
>                           @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.message)
>                       
>                   
>                   
>                       
>                           
>                       
>                   
>               }
>
> #### Follow Me! Im Awesome!
>
> #### and something else here
>
> © @DateTime.Now.Year - My ASP.NET Application
>
> @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")

Model:

> using System; using System.Collections.Generic; using System.Linq;
>   using System.Web; using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
>
> namespace ToDoListMaster.Models {
>       public class user
>       {
>           [Required, Display(Name ="First Name:")]
>           public string firstName { get; set; }
>
> ```
>     [Required, Display(Name = "Last Name:")]
>     public string lastName { get; set; }
>
>     [Required, Display(Name = "Phone Number:")]
>     [Phone]
>     public string phone { get; set; }
>
>     [Required, Display(Name = "Email Address:")]
>     [EmailAddress]
>     public string email { get; set; }
>
>     [Required, Display(Name = "Subject")]
>     public string subject { get; set; }
>
>     [Required, Display(Name = "Comments")]
>     [UIHint("MultilineText")]
>     public string message { get; set; }
> } }
> ```

Comment: Just checking. Do you have a Sent view in the view's folder?

Comment: yes I do. I originally had this form set up in an "email" view that redirected to the "Sent" view. I was able to get that to work fine. When I moved it over to the "_footer" view and had it rendered int he "_layout" I could not longer get it to work.

Comment: If you put a break point in the _footer action does it hit when you submit your form? If not edit your form with @using (Html.BeginForm("_footer", "Home")).

Comment: It was really just that easy! Thank you! Can you explain to me why exactly that worked?

Answer (score 0):

@Html.BeginForm without any overloads submits to it's own default view that rendered it. That is why it worked with it's own view. There are two parts to form submission HttpGet and HttpPost in MVC. By default whatever your action method renders the view a form will try to post to the same named action method with HttpPost attribute.

In your case, since you moved your form to a partial page, it is trying to post the form to the main view that it got rendered by. So you had to use the action name and controller name overload to your @Html.BeginForm method to direct it to the correct action method you wanted to post to.

In short,

```
@Html.BeginForm translates to <form method='post' action='whichever action rendered it'></form>

@using (Html.BeginForm("_footer", "Home")) transltes to <form method='post' action='home/_footer'></form>
```

You can always check your rendered html view by using chrome inspect to see exactly what it translates to.